# Adding WSDL to a project dynamically using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am looking for groovy script to add an wsdl to a project in SOAPUI dynamically at runtime using groovy scripts. i have tried the following code

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*

import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory


project = new WsdlProject()
//wsdl = new WsdlInterfaceFactory()

project.setName("Project1");

WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, "C:\\Manoj\\BIAScalarReads\\IDSRequestLIB\\IDS_Request_MeterData.wsdl", true)[0];
```

No new project is getting loaded in the SOAPUI. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a project, however then you don't add the project to the Workspace. To do so you must use the related method from [`Workspace` class](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/workspace/Workspace.html).

It possible to do so in a different ways. For example, create your project, save on disk and then load on the workspace in your `groovy script` testStep inside a testCase:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory

def project = new WsdlProject()
project.setName("Project1")
WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, 'path/to/yourWsdl', true)

// file to save the project
def projectFilePath = 'C:/temp/myProject.xml'
// save the project
project.saveAs(projectFilePath) 
// load the project from disc to workspace
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.importProject(projectFilePath)
```

Another possible and more compact way to do the same is using [`workspace.createProject`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/workspace/Workspace.html#createProject(java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) this way you avoid to save the disc and then import, to do it this way you can use the follow script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory

def workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace
def project =   workspace.createProject('Project2',new File('C:/temp/myProject.xml')) 
WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, 'path/to/yourWsdl', true)
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked fine, except the part project file path should be in // eg. C://temp://myProject.xml

Comment: @Manoj the path doesn't work for you with single `/`? ops strange. anyway nice to help you `:)`.